# Select2 4.x: How to actually limit the search input?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I refer to option `maximumInputLength`: Setting this to e.g. "5" displays a message "Please delete 3 characters" in case I enter a term of length 8. Nevertheless it's possible to enter any amount of characters.

While this may be desired in certain situations, it differs from how `<input type="text" maxlength="5">` works, as this would prevent any input of more than 5 characters.

So in order to have a consistent behaviour within my UI my question is: How to actually *limit* the input?

---

What I've tried so far: The message is generated in `function MaximumInputLength`, so I tried to override that function as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32117772/3890673), but without success. I get several errors such as "options is undefined", "decorated is undefined", ... While I still assume I'll have to somehow overwrite certain things the process to do so in select2 4.x is somewhat unclear to me, so any help is appreciated

---

EDIT: [velimir-tchatchevsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2628903/velimir-tchatchevsky)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39526616/3890673) pointed me to this workaround:

```
$('select').select2().on('select2:open', function() {
    $('.select2-search__field').attr('maxlength', 5);
});
```

Kind of hacky (what if the css class changes in future releases?), so I'd prefer a different solution, but this does the job

Comment: It won't work for the case when select2 is used in "tags" mode. That does the trick: ```$element.select2({...}); $element.data('select2').$container.find('.select2-search__field').attr('maxlength', 5);```

Comment: @AlexeyKosov that doesn't appear to be the case.  Perhaps because this was a different version before, or because the user updated their response, but if you look his code above, it will find all search fields in the page and update them.  Yours does so on a specific one, but either will work.  I've validated on my code which uses tags mode.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use simple jQuery to limit the input on key release in the example I also disable the input when the maximum length is reached:

```
$("input").keydown(function(e){
    if($("#input").val().length > 2){
          $("#input").val($("#input").val().substr(0, 3));
          $("#input").prop('disabled', true);
     }
});
```

Comment: `disabled="true"` isn't quite what I want, plus the input field isn't available until the drop-down opens, but this helped me to build a workaround, see updated question. Thanks! PS: Should be `attr()`, not `prop()`